# How to add mapping to fields in Salesforce surveys

Tags: community, survey, salesforce-survey

If anyone knows:

1. if we can add the Object field values on Salesforce native survey page as outputfield(not editable just for display values)
2. Also what are the limitations of using salesforce surveys as i'm deciding whether to switch from a third party survey tool to Salesforce native surveys
3. If these survey urls can handle queryparam sent to be displayed in survey

Answer (score 0):

Answers to #1 and #3 definitely NO.

Regarding #2, there are a lot of limitations.

But you can try Salesforce Surveys for free for the first 300 responses to your surveys.

Things have gotten better with the Winter '20 release, out now. You can use Process Builder to send survey invitation.

Also, the product is getting more visibility. At Dreamforce in a couple of weeks, Salesforce Survey is a "product" on Agenda Builder, and there are seven sessions. Two sessions will discuss the product road map.

If you want a lot of customization, take a look at Surveyforce from Salesforce Labs on AppExchange. It is free, and the source code is on Github.